# Retrieve git commit hash from a kernel module's srcversion

Tags: git, version-control, kernel-module, git-commit

Is there a way to retrieve git commit hash from a kernel module's srcversion?

I am using a pre-built module (installed, and I can see its info using modinfo). I need to know the version of the code when this module was compiled. I can see srcversion there; is it related to a git commit hash? The git commit hash is 40 chars whereas the srcversion is 23.

I can see this in modinfo:
[image]
And I know that this the source file:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/tcp_dctcp.c

Can I know which commit was used?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us an example of what you are talking about.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks. Updated the question

Comment: `srcversion` is a hash sum of the module contents. So, it's not easy to retrieve version, though your filename shows that quite likely the module is from a kernel sources based on v5.2.0-rc3. What you need is a SHA-1 of the Git tree from which that kernel had been built.